# could some one explane this java loop for me

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;

class arel {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] number = new int[7];
        for(int roll = 1; roll < 100; roll++){
            ++number[1+rand.nextInt(6)];
        }
        System.out.println("Index\tValue");
        for(int count = 1; count<number.length; count++){
            System.out.println(count+"\t"+number[count]);
        }
    }
}
```

`++number[1+rand.nextInt(6)];` is that line mean insert random number for each index?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the line `++number[1+rand.nextInt(6)];`?

Comment: `++number[1+rand.nextInt(6)]` increases a random member 1 through 6 of the array `number` by one

Comment: You are pre-incrementing an element of an array whilst spreading fog all over the meaning of your code here.  What is happening here is that a tally is being incremented.  I'd do this instead:  number[1 + rand.nextInt(6)] += 1;

Answer (score 2):

```
++number[1 + rand.Next(6)];
```

is similar to:

```
// get a random number between 1 and 6
int index = 1 + rand.nextInt(6); 

// increase the element of the array at the given random index by 1
number[index] = number[index] + 1;
```

Comment: oky and what ++number does mean, its equale to number[1] = xxx then number[2] = xxx?

Comment: @user805752, no, it means that it increments the value of the element stored at the given random index of the array by one. It is equivalent to `number[index] = number[index] + 1;` as I showed in my answer.

Comment: and  what for(int roll = 1; roll < 100; roll++){ mean? please give me steps !

Comment: @user805752, it is a loop that executes 99 times and on each iteration it increments a value at a random index in the given array. I think you really should familiarize yourself with some basic language features like what an array means, a for loop, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

The line `++number[1+rand.nextInt(6)];` takes advantage of the fact that arrays in Java are 0-initialized and order of operations.

A random number between 1 and 6 is generated. The appropriate index of the array `number` is incremented based on the random value. This operation is looped on many times. At the end, a second loop is used to print out the number of times each value was printed.

However, the 0-index of the `number` array is never used by this code. In effect, it's wasted space that must be (and is) accounted for in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

What it's doing:

1. Creating a random number generator with the default seed.
2. Creating an array with 7 elements (indexed as 0 through 6)
3. Looping 99 times (with roll from 1 to 99)
4. As others have said, incrementing the value of one of the array elements by one at random. Note that the zero-index is never incremented.
5. The rest of the code outputs the values that have been counted in indices 1 through 6.

The fact that the writer has ignored the zero-index is a bit of a smell.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] number = new int[7]; // first index=0, last=6. 
                           // After creation all elements are 0
```

In for-loop you call 99 times the line: `++number[1+rand.nextInt(6)];`

```
++number[index]; // it's the same: number[index]=number[index]+1
```

`rand.nextInt(n)` method return random integer between 0..n-1. [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)

In your example you add one to that random number, so you have random number between: 1..6

Now you can understand all the code so I'm sure you will know what it does. Notice first index of your array is zero and is never changed.